# Function page syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, function

I can't find the missing curly brace, but I am getting this message `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /site/public_html/core/functions/users.php on line 75"`

For the following code..

```php
<?php

function activate($email, $email_code) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

    if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }


function change_password ($user_id, $password) {
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $password = md5($password);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$password' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
}

function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
    email($register_data['email'], 'Activate your account', "
    Hello " . $register_data['username'] . ", \n\n You need to activate your account, so use     the link below: \n\nhttp://www.mysite.com/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] .   "&email_code=" . $register_data['email_code'] . "\n\n~Admin~ ");
}

function user_count() {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM `users` WHERE `active` =  1"), 0);
}

function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args &gt; 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =   $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }

}

function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` =1"), 0) ==1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username ($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id'));
}

function login ($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}

?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Never heard of indentation?

Comment: I think the 1st function is not closing, after the `else` closing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging some code that could easily be solved by using a decent IDE.

Comment: What prevents you from finding that missing brace?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you missed `}`

it should be

```
function activate($email, $email_code) {
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
} <---missing bracket here
```

Comment: downvoter please let a comment telling why , maybe i improve my answer

Comment: I don't think his missing brace belongs at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, he is missing it.  That's not what's being argued.  It's the placement of the brace.  I don't think he wants his function to include functions.

Comment: sorry it was mistake . i edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `activate()` function is missing its closing bracket `}`.

```
function activate($email, $email_code) {
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

  if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

} /* MISSING BRACKET */

function change_password ($user_id, $password) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `function` is missing a closing brace `}`:

```
function activate($email, $email_code) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

    if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Also, indentation would help find problems like this easier (and an IDE that matches your braces)

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your first function, so just add `}` at the end

```
function activate($email, $email_code) {
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

oh, and by the way stop using the regular PHP mysql_* functions. They will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5, so take a look at [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think the 1st function "activate" is not closing, add `}` after the else closing.

```
function activate($email, $email_code) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

    if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
^
here
```